# Define VIM fold for stack frames

Tags: vim, callstack

While programming I'm often dumping call stack frames to my logfiles so I can see how we got to this point, etc. To avoid clutter, I want to "fold" them out of the way most of the time.

Stack frames have this pattern:

```
  ...
  Normal logfile information that is not part of the frame
   0# first line of the frame                  <fold>
   1# next line of the frame                   <fold>
   ...                                          ...
  99# main                                     <fold>

  More information that is not part of the frame
  ...
```

I have been using "foldmethod=manual" and going to the lines that begin with    `0#` and typing `zf}` (which says to fold until the next blank line). If I build a macro to do this on all the `0#` lines, then it does exactly what I expect. My logfile will correctly look like this:

```
  ...
  Normal logfile information that is not part of the frame
+  0# first line of the frame                  <fold>

  More information that is not part of the frame
  ...
```

Instead, I want to do this fold automatically using `foldmethod=expr`. My approach is...

I have a vim syntax file for my logfiles, and define these three lines:

```
set foldexpr=(getline(v:1num)[0]==\"^\\s*\\d+#\")?1:0
set foldmethod=expr
set foldenable
```

I've also tried `set foldexpr=getline(v:1num)=~'^\\s*\\d+#'` and `set foldexpr=getline(v:1num)=~'^\\s*\\d+\\#'`

The pattern I use (to define a foldlevel of '1') is:

- start of line
- 0 or more whitespace
- 1 or more digits
- the hash/pound/octothorpe character
  All other lines should have a foldlevel of '0'.

Once loaded in vim, using `:set` I can see these options as I expect:

```
 foldexpr=(getline(v:1num)[0]=="^\s*\d+#")?1:0
 foldmethod=expr
```

No joy. No folds. How can I debug this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

edit: I have vim 7.4 "huge", that was compiled with "+folding".

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From a cursory glance… You use `v:1num` instead of `v:lnum`. I suggest you get a better monospaced font.

Comment: @romainl. Ha Ha! That's it!    Thank you!